# Пустой NuGet пакет при скачивании

Tags: c#, сервер, nuget

Развернул свой Nuget Server на удаленном хосте. Также собрал два NuGet пакета и добавил их напрямую в репозиторий сервера, и выкладываю сервак вместе с ними. Проблема в том, что один пакет устанавливается нормально. А от второго я получаю лишь dll размером 4КБ, который содержит лишь Class1.cs и все. 
Проверял на серверной тачке все лежит как надо. Два nupkg, смотрел что внутри, все тоже в порядке. dll размером 32КБ, как и должно быть. 
Не могу понять как это возможно, на серваке в принципе нет такого dll, который скачивается.
Кстати по прямой ссылке вида [http://(сервер)/nuget/Packages(Id='пакет',Version='1.0.0')/Download](http://(%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)/nuget/Packages(Id='%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82,Version='1.0.0')/Download) скачивается то, что нужно. А в менеджере пакетов в студии нет.

На всякий скину xml

```
<entry>
<id>http://XXX/nuget/Packages(Id='XXX',Version='1.0.0')</id>
<category term="NuGet.Server.Core.DataServices.ODataPackage" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<link rel="edit" href="http://XXX/nuget/Packages(Id='XXX',Version='1.0.0')" />
<link rel="self" href="http://XXX/nuget/Packages(Id='XXX',Version='1.0.0')" />
<title type="text">XX</title>
<published>2019-08-28T15:33:54Z</published>
<updated>2019-08-28T15:33:54Z</updated>
<author>
  <name>XXX</name>
</author>
<m:action metadata="http://XXX/nuget/$metadata#Container.Download" title="Download" target="http://XXX/nuget/Packages(Id='XXX',Version='1.0.0')/Download" />
<content type="application/zip" src="http://XXX/nuget/Packages(Id='XXX',Version='1.0.0')/Download" />
<m:properties>
  <d:Id>XXX</d:Id>
  <d:Version>1.0.0</d:Version>
  <d:NormalizedVersion>1.0.0</d:NormalizedVersion>
  <d:IsPrerelease m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsPrerelease>
  <d:Title m:null="true" />
  <d:Authors>XXX</d:Authors>
  <d:Owners>XXX</d:Owners>
  <d:IconUrl m:null="true" />
  <d:LicenseUrl m:null="true" />
  <d:ProjectUrl m:null="true" />
  <d:DownloadCount m:type="Edm.Int32">-1</d:DownloadCount>
  <d:RequireLicenseAcceptance m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:RequireLicenseAcceptance>
  <d:DevelopmentDependency m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:DevelopmentDependency>
  <d:Description>Package Description</d:Description>
  <d:Summary m:null="true" />
  <d:ReleaseNotes m:null="true" />
  <d:Published m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-08-28T15:33:54.6086454Z</d:Published>
  <d:LastUpdated m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-08-28T15:33:54.6086454Z</d:LastUpdated>
  <d:Dependencies>Newtonsoft.Json:12.0.2:netstandard2.0</d:Dependencies>
  <d:PackageHash>Dr2G/gnXGebfTCTMjWjPled3JcmjFUujnH8R41tOjTphtfhFSUegfEBKI4LwQUIuiDV6JHkY5Kvf47aXYsMiMQ==</d:PackageHash>
  <d:PackageHashAlgorithm>SHA512</d:PackageHashAlgorithm>
  <d:PackageSize m:type="Edm.Int64">31763</d:PackageSize>
  <d:Copyright m:null="true" />
  <d:Tags m:null="true" />
  <d:IsAbsoluteLatestVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsAbsoluteLatestVersion>
  <d:IsLatestVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsLatestVersion>
  <d:Listed m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:Listed>
  <d:VersionDownloadCount m:type="Edm.Int32">-1</d:VersionDownloadCount>
  <d:MinClientVersion m:null="true" />
  <d:Language m:null="true" />
</m:properties>
```

Comment: Кстати, если заменить руками dll полученный из менеджера пакетов, на тот, что напрямую скачиваю с nuget сервера, вижу свою либу.

Comment: Скорее всего вы собирали тестовую версию когда-то, с таким же имёнем и версией, и в локальном кэше остался старый пакет. Почистите все подряд: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: спасибо. попробую и отпишусь о результатах.

Answer (score 0):

> Скорее всего вы собирали тестовую версию когда-то, с таким же имёнем и версией, и в локальном кэше остался старый пакет.

Похоже дело действительно было в кэше. Поднял версию пакета, проблема исчезла